# Git: when running "git remote -v" I get no upstream setting

Tags: git, github

When I run git remote -v from my master branch I get origin (fetch) and (pull) set correctly but nothing is returned for upstream for either (fetch) or (pull).  I can do "git pull" without specifying an upstream branch.  I can't understand how I can be tracking the upstream during a pull but not returning any info?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not clear on your question. Can you clarify? Are you wondering why `git remote -v` doesn't get your repo synced with upstream but `git pull` does?

Comment: I'm also not clear on what you mean when you say `git remote -v` gives you correct information, and that `git pull` works, but that "pull is not returning any info". Normally, it would at least say `Everything up-to-date` if there's nothing to pull (i.e. `fetch` + `merge`).

Answer (score 0):

`origin` is the conventional name for the remote server. So in your case, `git pull` command would be fetching from `origin`.

```
kuah-air:rails kuahyeow$ git remote -v
origin  git://github.com/rails/rails.git (fetch)
origin  git://github.com/rails/rails.git (push)
```

Note on terms : Some people use and add `upstream` remotes when pulling/forking from a project. In that case they would have more origin and upstream remotes. e.g.

```
kuah-air:doorman kuahyeow$ git remote -v
upstream    https://github.com/movableink/doorman.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/movableink/doorman.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:kuahyeow/doorman.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:kuahyeow/doorman.git (push)
```